# Microsoft Access 2010 - Dynamic query

Tags: sql, ms-access, macros, view, vba

I have an access web database that several users will need to log in to. The database contains a table of products.

The challenge is, every user needs to only see a subset of these products and never see the whole list.

At the moment i have some code to modify an existing query based on the logged in user's details. As they log in, some tempvars are created and these are used to modify the query criteria.

This works well when the first user logs in, but the moment the next user logs in, the query is modified again and the product list refreshes and now his products are shown and not the first users! Im thinking i need to dynamically create a permanent query for each user on log in?

Or is a better way to accomplish what im trying ? im quite new to access and struggling. Can anyone assist please?

Here is my code so far:

**Button on login form has the following code that collects the user's details**

```
Private Sub cmdLoginMine_Click()
Dim ID as long, strEmpName as string,strZondsc as string,strgrpdsc as string

ID = DLookup("ID", "Employees", "Login='" & Me.txtUser.Value & "'")
strEmpName = DLookup("FullName", "Employees", "Login='" & Me.txtUser.Value & "'")
strgrpdsc = DLookup("MyGrpdscs", "Employees", "Login='" & Me.txtUser.Value & "'")
strzondsc = DLookup("MyZondscs", "Employees", "Login='" & Me.txtUser.Value & "'")

TempVars.Add "tmpEmployeeID", ID
TempVars.Add "tmpEmployeeName", txtUser.Value
```

**I then call a function that modifies the existing query, populating it with this users details for the criteria**

```
qryEdit strgrpdsc, strzondsc, ID


Sub qryEdit(strgrpdsc As String, strzondsc As String, ID As Long)
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim qdfOLD As String

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("InventoryQryforDS")
    With qdf
        .SQL = "SELECT Products.ProductCode, Products.ProductName, Products.GRPDSC, Categories.Category, Inventory.Available " & _
               "FROM (Categories INNER JOIN Products ON Categories.ID = Products.CategoryID) INNER JOIN Inventory ON Products.ID = Inventory.ProductID " & _
               "WHERE Products.GRPDSC in (" & strgrpdsc & ") and Categories.Category in (" & strzondsc & ") and products.ownersid =" & ID & _
               " ORDER BY Products.ProductCode"


    End With
Set qdf = Nothing

End Sub
```

The results of the query are shown on a form, which is what is currently requerying and showing the wrong data.

Thanks

**EDIT** - THe data is shown on a form, linked to one of the new style navigation buttons as shown.The **recordsource** property of the form is the query that's populated as described above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions/corrections to your approach to solving this issue.

When using DLookup, make sure they are enclosed within **Nz()** function, if the value you are looking for is not found you might be facing troubles of assigning a Null value to a Data Type that cannot handle Null. Anything other than Variant type will suffer.

You seem to do not one but **four DLookup**'s on the table. This could be very expensive. This could be minimized by using a simple RecordSet Object.

I would not use **TempVars** much as they could be tricky to understand and implement.

Why are you **editing the Query**? This could again be a bit expensive in terms of memory. How are you showing the list of Products? In DataSheet or ComboBox or LsitBox? You could yet again change the RecordSource or RowSource of the Objects rather than editing the Query itself.

Finally, your users should all have a **separate copy** of the Front End file. Not one copy used by 20-30 people. If the files is restricted to be used by one person, then the code should work regardless of being modified. As the user will have access to the right data at all times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.How would i use a recordset object in place of the Dlookups please? what i was trying to do was get the values eg employee id and name from the employees table, based on the inputs in the login form that the user fills. Im also not sold on the idea of tempvars if im honest but thought they would work in this situation. I am editing the query,( and perhaps this is misguided) in an attempt to create a dynamic "view" for the user, based on his ID number. The products table has an ID number column and im trying to filter the product list that the user will see based on this.

Comment: As for having a separate copy of the front end, i tried splitting the database, but as this is an access web database (based on a microsoft template that i have modified), some of the data macros did not work after splitting it. Have you worked with web databases before and if so how did you go about splitting them. cheers